# How to show error message when redirected on other screen?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I want to send message when redirected to other page. Redirection is working fine. I am using this.

```
    $.post(url, formData, function (result) {

                    if (result.redirect) {
                        window.location.href = result.redirect;

                        return;
                    }
}
```

Redirection is working fine but i need to show a message on other screen. how i can do this?

Comment: You could add a querstring or Routeparameter to `result.redirect` and check for it on the new page. If it is present display your message

Comment: Set the `session` variable for error message, check whether session error exists and unset it after displaying it..

Comment: very smart idea @serv. It works. Thanks

Comment: Hiba, will these error message be based on user privileges? (i.e. a manager has access but a normal user does not)